# Possible to run Logic Apps and Azure Functions (or equivalent functionality) in Service Fabric?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-service-fabric, azure-logic-apps

We have a solution that is leveraging (among other things) Azure Functions and Azure Logic Apps.  Per company policy, we can no longer leverage any stack that runs on abstracted hardware where our auditing code can't run (i.e. there is no way to install our compliance bits on the hardware that executes Logic App or Azure Function code).  We are migrating all of our services and VMs into Service Fabric.  I have not found any way to move or replicate the functionality of these two offerings in Service Fabric.  Is there any way to do this?  If not, is there any suggestion for an alternate solution?

Additionally, we are using Azure Scheduler to schedule jobs.  That is being deprecated and the recommended alternative is Logic Apps.  That puts us in the same boat as above.

Thanks,
~john

Answer (score 2):

You can run Azure Functions in service fabric - at least the app. All function apps can run in a docker container. You would need to manage and control scaling and availability but could use same triggers and tools.

We have also been doing some effort to allow functions to run on user-managed infra with Kubernetes. KEDA provides function like scaling to functions containers in Kubernetes and we’re interested to add even more capabilities. Hope this helps - feel free to ping me for ?s @jeffhollan on Twitter.